# Post method in angular giving error 406 (Not Acceptable)

Tags: python, django, xml, angular, python-2.7

I am trying to call post XML data in angular & get posted XML in python(Django) and save it to mongodb, but its giving mi error 406 (Not Acceptable) and detail":"Could not satisfy the request Accept header.

In component.ts :

```
let headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/xml');
headers.append('Accept', 'application/xml');
let body = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?> " + 
           "<note> " + 
           "<to>Tove</to> " + 
           "<from>Jani</from> " + 
           "<heading>Reminder</heading> " + 
           "<body>Dont forget me this weekend!</body> " + 
           "</note>";
this.http.post(url, body, { headers: headers })
  .subscribe(data => {
    console.log(data);
  });
```

In views.py

```
def post(self, request):
  original_response = request.data
  save_response = LenderResponse(lender_response=str(original_response))
  return Response(original_response)
```

Comment: What framework are you using on the Python side? Are you sure it supports XML natively, or that you've configured it correctly to do so?

Comment: I am new to python ...where i can check my framework

Comment: You probably had to install and import it, if you gave a [mcve] people could see for themselves.

Comment: I am using Django but not sure about the XML support.

Comment: Then a starting point might be https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/serialization/

Comment: I am trying to post xml data in angular and try to get that post data in python view.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. At the very least, you should be able to narrow it down to whether you're failing to send correct data or failing to receive it, e.g. by using an alternative client or looking at the request you're actually making.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184512/discussion-between-dignesh-and-jonrsharpe).

Comment: Is there a specific reason you need to use xml?

Comment: @cricket_007 Unfortunately yes.

Answer (score 2):

`406: Not Acceptable` means that the server cannot return the data in the format that you requested using the `Accept` header.

You are passing the `Accept: application/xml` header, but for some reason, your server does not support that response type. you should either pass a different header with a format the server knows how to work with or change the server code to support the `application/xml` response type.

For Django (as it looks to be your server framework of choice), you should use the [REST Framework XML](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/renderers/#xml) plugin.